# How to retrieve json from firebase which has nested child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported json file to firebase real-time database you can follow the screenshot
https://ibb.co/wyLDPC8  "database structure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
 DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();   
 dbRef.child("categories").addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
           for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = snapshot.child("names").getValue().toString();  // it will give names node string

             /// To Fetch Quotes
             DataSnapshot quotesSnapshot = snapshot.child("qoutes");
            for (DataSnapshot quoteSingleSnpashot : quotesSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 String quote = quoteSingleSnpashot.child("quote").getValue().toString();  // it will give names node string
            }

           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }

 });
}
```

Comment: how to get qoutes from it

Comment: i have debug that its not entering into second loop

Comment: spelling mistake, in my code, key name is "quotes" please change it to "qoutes", as in your database

Comment: thank you so much, sir, it's working now I have one more query if I have a list of data with a different key then how can I retrieve the total data                 String quote = quoteSingleSnpashot.child("quote").getValue().toString();         i cant use child()

Comment: please give me an example database snapshot, as you given before, then I'll be able to tell you.

Comment: in this case, you can do it inside the loop
 String quote1 = quoteSingleSnpashot.child("quote1").getValue().toString(); and  String quote2 = quoteSingleSnpashot.child("quote2").getValue().toString();

Comment: if you don't know the keys, then you can add loop on any Datasnapshot like this. for(DataSnapshot snap : snapShot.getChildren()) {
    snap.getValue().toString();
}

Comment: I mean you need to add a 3rd nested loop to iterate all the quotes present inside.

Comment: thank you so much sir, you saved my life thanx a lot  Sir like if I get any other query how can I ask you can you share your contact information please

Comment: you are welcome. You can ask me here, or post a new question :)

Comment: I have the last question whatever the 3rd nested loop data is there in firebase send data to next activity as per the 1st loop data in recyclerview   adapter onclickListner am not able to understand that part

Comment: you need to create your model arraylist in the way that 1 class contains arraylist of other class. like cateogory class contains an arraylist of quote class. and to your adapter pass category arraylist. Its bit tricky but you have to do that :)